# How to remove letters?

Tags: vb.net

i just wanna ask:
i have a label40.text 
with a content of {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
and i also have have a label39.text that will change its output everytime a certain changes happens.

My question is
How can i embed this simulation through a code?

If Label39.text = "a" then the content of label40.text "a" will be remove and the list of alphabets will be remain alphabetically.

I want that also to be happen anytime my label39.text will change its value "RANDOMLY"

Example if label39.text = "a,b,c,d,x,z" then
label40.text = "e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y"

this is my code so far

```
Dim patterns As String
        patterns = Label39.Text
        Dim tobefollow As String
        tobefollow = Label40.Text
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(patterns, tobefollow)
        If Regex.IsMatch(patterns, tobefollow) Then
               'this where i will put my code to make my example 
        End If
```

Comment: You'll find this a lot easier if you don't confuse your sets of letters with a string representation of them. {a,b,c} != "a,b,c". Oh and give your labels proper names.

Comment: can u please help me improve these? can u give me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that you are populating the `patterns` and `tobefollow` variables wrongly (you were doing it right in the other question); it should be:

```
patterns = Label40.Text
tobefollow = Label39.Text
```

Also bear in mind that what you want can easily be accomplished without relying on `Regex`; for example via:

```
If (Label40.Text.ToLower().Contains(Label39.Text.ToLower())) Then
       'this where i will put my code to make my example 
End If
```

Regarding what you want this time, you can rely on `.Replace`: `.Replace("text to be deleted", "")` will remove this letter; but you have also to account for the commas. Code to be put inside the condition:

```
Dim origString As String = Label40.Text
Label40.Text = Label40.Text.ToLower().Replace(Label39.Text.ToLower() & ",", "")
If (origString = Label40.Text) Then
    'It means that it does not have any comma, that is, refers to the last letter
    Label40.Text = Label40.Text.ToLower().Replace("," & Label39.Text.ToLower(), "")
End If
```

Comment: @CrixalisPaul you are welcome and my name is varocarbas, not sir :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer would to use the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6x627e5f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and the [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Methods to breakdown your strings into individual characters then remove them from the List and join them back together. Here is a Function that does that:

```
Private Function RemoveLetters(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
    Dim sep() As String = {","}
    Dim list1 As List(Of String) = str1.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList
    Dim list2 As List(Of String) = str2.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList

    For Each s As String In list2
        list1.Remove(s)
    Next
    Return String.Join(",", list1)
End Function
```

you would use it like this:

```
Label40.Text = RemoveLetters(Label40.Text, Label39.Text)
```